# Weblogic 12.1.3 - CXF 3.x - REST - Deployment Error

Tags: java, spring, rest, cxf, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy a simple 'CXF 3.1.2' REST application on Weblogic 12.1.3 and get this error. (But works on Tomcat 8)

**weblogic.application.ModuleException: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does
not contain any root resource classes.**

I also tried to deploy the below library in Weblogic, still the same error.

C:\Oracle\Middleware2\Oracle_Home\wlserver\common\deployable-libraries\jax-rs-2.0.war

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>mdm</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**spring-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Service -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.jai.service" />

    <jaxrs:server id="mdmCxfServer" address="/"  >

        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="airlineService" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

        <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </jaxrs:extensionMappings>

        <jaxrs:providers>
            <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider" />
        </jaxrs:providers>

        <jaxrs:features>
            <cxf:logging />
        </jaxrs:features>
    </jaxrs:server>
```

**Full Error log**

```
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:35 PM weblogic.jaxrs.server.portable.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer onStartup
    INFO: Number of JAX-RS specific classes to be examined:22
    Aug 20, 2015 5:36:42 PM org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl reload
    INFO: Reloading registered services.
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:44 PM org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl load
    INFO: Loaded 4 services.
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:44 PM org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl load
    INFO: Loaded 4 services.
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:44 PM weblogic.jaxrs.server.portable.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer onStartup
    INFO: The list of resource packages:org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base org.apache.cxf.jaxr
    s.provider com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:44 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
    INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:44 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Aug 20 17:37:44 BST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:44 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml]
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:44 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor <init>
    INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:44 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
    INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:44 PM org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean createNativeEntityManagerFact
    ory
    INFO: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:44 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
    INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
            name: default
            ...]
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:44 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:44 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
    INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:44 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
    INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:45 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:45 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
    INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:45 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
    INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
    INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
    INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
    INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:46 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
    INFO: HHH000261: Table found: AIRLINES
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:46 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
    INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [country_code, iata, countrycode, name, callsign, alias, icao, id, call_sign]
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:46 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
    INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:46 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
    INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [sys_c0013697]
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:46 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
    INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:46 PM org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl initDestination
    INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be /
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:46 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
    INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2311 ms
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:46 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
    INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation
      com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base
      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider
      com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json
      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:46 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
    INFO: No root resource classes found.
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:46 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
    INFO: Provider classes found:
      class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.FormEncodingProvider
      class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.RequestDispatcherProvider
      class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.ValidationExceptionMapper
      class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.MultipartProvider
      class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider
      class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.SourceProvider
      class com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
      class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.JAXRSBeanValidationOutInterceptor
      class com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
      class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.XSLTJaxbProvider
      class com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JsonParseExceptionMapper
      class com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonMappingExceptionMapper
      class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyWriter
      class com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonParseExceptionMapper
      class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.XPathProvider
      class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.DataBindingProvider
      class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.DataSourceProvider
      class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyReader
      class com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JsonMappingExceptionMapper
      class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider
      class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.JAXRSBeanValidationInInterceptor
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:46 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
    INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.18.1 02/19/2014 03:28 AM'
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:46 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules <init>
    SEVERE: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    <Aug 20, 2015 5:37:46 PM BST> <Error> <com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules> <BEA-000000> <The Re
    sourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.>
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:46 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
    SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.RequestDispatcherProvider.setMessageCo
    ntext(org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext) at parameter at index 9
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.Mu
    ltipartProvider.mc
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider.setMessageContext(
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext) at parameter at index 1
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.So
    urceProvider.context
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider.setMessageContext(
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext) at parameter at index 15
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setMess
    ageContext(org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext) at parameter at index 3
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.Fo
    rmEncodingProvider.mc
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setMess
    ageContext(org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext) at parameter at index 3
    <Aug 20, 2015 5:37:46 PM BST> <Error> <com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors> <BEA-000000> <The following errors and warnings
     have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.RequestDispatcherProvider.setMessageCo
    ntext(org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext) at parameter at index 9
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.Mu
    ltipartProvider.mc
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider.setMessageContext(
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext) at parameter at index 1
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.So
    urceProvider.context
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider.setMessageContext(
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext) at parameter at index 15
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setMess
    ageContext(org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext) at parameter at index 3
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.Fo
    rmEncodingProvider.mc
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setMess
    ageContext(org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext) at parameter at index 3>
    <Aug 20, 2015 5:37:46 PM BST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "Jersey" failed to preload on startup in Web applica
    tion: "mdm.war".
    com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.

            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    >
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:46 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext doClose
    INFO: Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Aug 20 17:37:44 BST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    Aug 20, 2015 5:37:46 PM org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean destroy
    INFO: Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    <Aug 20, 2015 5:37:47 PM BST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request w
    ith ID "51293817685089" for task "14". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: com.sun.jersey.api.container.Con
    tainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes."
    weblogic.application.ModuleException: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does
    not contain any root resource classes.
            at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
            at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    Caused By: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resour
    ce classes.
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    >
    <Aug 20, 2015 5:37:47 PM BST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 9
     task for the application "mdm_service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".>
    <Aug 20, 2015 5:37:47 PM BST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for
     application "mdm_service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".>
    <Aug 20, 2015 5:37:47 PM BST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
    weblogic.application.ModuleException: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does
    not contain any root resource classes.:com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException:The ResourceConfig instance does
    not contain any root resource classes.
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    >
```

Comment: I think you should use the weblogic.xml file to prefer the cxf libs from your deployment and not the ones from weblogic

Comment: @DanielJipa Thanks for that I come across such post but could not figure out what exactly to put in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I figured out need to add the below code in weblogic.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app 
               http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.7/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

        <library-ref>
            <library-name>jax-rs</library-name>
            <specification-version>2.0</specification-version>
            <exact-match>false</exact-match>
        </library-ref>

    </weblogic-web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

We actually got the same error, and we were not using CXF, but somehow WebLogic's (12.1.3) embedded Jersey implementation seemed to try to load something from the jackson dependencies which were included in our application and this then failed and caused the application deployment to fail, too.

The solution for us was to use the suggestion from http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/jaxrs-cxf-deployment-issues-on-weblogic-12c-td5742398.html, i.e. to add the following to weblogic.xml, so that WebLogic does not try to do that:

```
    <prefer-application-resources>
        <resource-name>META-INF/services/*</resource-name>
    </prefer-application-resources>
```